# What is the answer to the Kelvin problem if restriced our selves to isohedral polyhedra?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, tessellations

A few days ago I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494037/what-is-the-analogon-of-the-hexagonal-grid-in-3-dimensional-space-rhombic-dodec) question. It turned out to be a known unsolved problem in mathematics: The Kelvin problem.
Now I'd like to slightly change the question:

What is the optimal way to divide 3-space into pieces of equal volume with the least total surface area, whereby only isohedral polyhedra are allowed?

I hope, this will be easier to solve than the original Kelvin problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't many [isohedra](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Isohedron.html) (all faces the same) that are also [space-filling polyhedra](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Space-FillingPolyhedron.html). Two of them are the cube and the rhombic dodecahedron.  A third is a [space-filling tetrahedron](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SpaceFillingTetrahedra/), called "Sommerville 1" or "Baumgartner T", with vertex set $(001, 021, 110, 112)$.

From the limited selection, the rhombic dodecahedron is optimal.